# Why does the colour of the same compound (e.g. magnesium nitride) differ?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color, solid-state-chemistry

When I am searching the colour of $\ce{Mg3N2}$ I came across photos showing different colours: **greenish-yellow** on [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Magnesium_nitride.jpg),
and some other **just yellow** on [some Google Images results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=magnesium+nitride).

I am eager to know what causes some samples to be bit greenish.

Comment: Maybe due to impurities, the color differs.

Comment: Particle size and polymorphism would also affect the color of a solid.

Comment: Privacy note: be very cautious when you post a link to the Google search results. Not only the address string looks messy, it also contains private info such as your device and browser names in plane text. There are several browser extensions that fix that and create a short nice-looking URL without using services like tinyurl; at the moment, I personally use [ClearURLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearurls/lckanjgmijmafbedllaakclkaicjfmnk?hl=en).

Answer (score 4):

Minor differences in color are likely either due to impurities or due to intrinsic crystal defects such as [f-centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-center). For example, $\ce{ZnO}$ is often a shade of yellow, rather than pure white, due to those defects. In alkali halides, [h-centers](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.52.4017) are similar defects giving rise to colors. You can easily [create color centers in $\ce{NaCl}$ with a spark coil](https://archive.education.mrsec.wisc.edu/background/F_center/index.htm) in just a few minutes.

Another possibility is that there are mixtures of different allotropes, or polymorphic forms. An extreme example is transparent diamond vs. black graphite. BTW, [diamonds having varied colors due to impurities (e.g. nitrogen) and to intrinsic defects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_defects_in_diamond#Isolated_carbon_interstitial) are useful in [studying quantum phenomena](https://www.wired.com/story/these-perfectly-imperfect-diamonds-are-built-for-quantum-physics/), as well as gems.